# Generate series (row-major order) in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion

I'm trying to generate a series in a general way in SQL (basically emulate nested loops).

Suppose we have N lower/upper bounds: l_1:u_1, ..., l_N:u_N, I want to generate a table

```
col_1 | col_2 | ... | col_N
------+-------+-----+------
l_1   | l_2   | ... | l_N
l_1   | l_2   | ... | l_N+1
l_1   | l_2   | ... | l_N+2
         ...
l_1   | l_2   | ... | u_N
l_1   | l_2+1 | ... | l_N
l_1   | l_2+1 | ... | l_N+1
         ...
u_1   | u_2   | ... | u_N
------+-------+-----+------
```

E.g. for 1:2,2:4 the result would be

```
col_1 | col_2 
------+-------
1     | 2     
1     | 3     
1     | 4     
2     | 2     
2     | 3     
2     | 4     
------+-------
```

Probably a WITH RECURSIVE query would be the way to go, but it's hard to wrap my head around it.

---

I've come up with this query for now, which uses `WITH RECURSION` instead of `generate_series`, but not sure how to parametrize it to work for different bounds:

```
WITH RECURSIVE T(n) AS ( 
 SELECT 1 AS n
 FROM (VALUES(1)) AS CN
  UNION
 SELECT n+1 AS n FROM T where n < 3
)
SELECT col1.n, col2.n, col1.n * col2.n
FROM T AS col1, T AS col2;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And what have you actually tried?

Comment: I'm looking for an implementation-independent solution, but verifying it in PostgreSQL just in case. So far I'm pretty stuck, trying to come up with some recursive query that would make it work for a fixed N=2 for example.

Comment: A recursive CTE is not the way to go... [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 1](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) - This is written with SQL Server in mind but the logic is transferable, a recursive CTE is just a glorified loop, yet people seem to think it is an acceptable set based alternative because of it's use with hierarchical problems. With Postgresql you can use `generate_series` to increment your data.

Comment: The result is simply cross joining the dimensions, in PostgreSQL it's a simple query: SELECT * FROM
  generate_series(1, 2) AS col_1, 
  generate_series(2, 4) as col2

Comment: dnoeth, that brings me very close! I just can't use generate_series, so I've come up with this now:

Comment: But still need to figure out how to parametrize it, without writing a function:

    WITH RECURSIVE T(n) AS ( 
     SELECT 1 AS n
     FROM (VALUES(1)) AS CN
      UNION
     SELECT n+1 AS n FROM T where n < 3
    )
    SELECT col1.n, col2.n, col1.n * col2.n FROM T AS col1, T AS col2;